# Passing from JCE to Bouncy Castle (Blowfish)

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, jce

I need to convert a JCE based code to a Bouncy Castle based code. I'm completely new to Bouncy Castle and couldn't find a easy-to-understand introduction to this topic in general or my issue specifically. This is the JCE based class:

```java
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE;

public class JCEBlowfishEncrypterDecrypter {
    
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "Blowfish";
    public static SecretKeySpec key;

    public static String crypt(String msg, String k) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec key = init(k);
        return Hex.byte2hex(intCrypt(msg, key));
    }

    public static String decrypt(String msg, String k) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec key = init(k);
        return new String(intDecrypt(Hex.hex2byte(msg), key));
    }

    private static byte[] intCrypt(String msg, SecretKeySpec key) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(1, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes());
    }

    private static byte[] intDecrypt(byte encrypted[], SecretKeySpec key) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(2, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    }

    private static SecretKeySpec init(String myKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SunJCE sunJce = new SunJCE();
        Security.addProvider(sunJce);
        byte raw[] = myKey.getBytes();
        return new SecretKeySpec(raw, ALGORITHM);
    }

}
```

... And this is the Bouncy Castle based class:

```java
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.BufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.BlowfishEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PKCS7Padding;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;

public class BouncyCastleBlowfishEncrypterDecrypter {

    public static String crypt(String msg, String key) throws Exception {
        PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new BlowfishEngine(), new PKCS7Padding());
        cipher.init(true, new KeyParameter(key.getBytes()));
        byte[] inputAsBytes = msg.getBytes();
        byte[] encryptedAsBytes = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(inputAsBytes.length)];
        int numberOfBytesCopiedOnEncryptedAsBytes = cipher.processBytes(inputAsBytes, 0, inputAsBytes.length,
                encryptedAsBytes, 0);
        cipher.doFinal(encryptedAsBytes, numberOfBytesCopiedOnEncryptedAsBytes);
        return Hex.byte2hex(encryptedAsBytes);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String msg, String key) throws Exception {
        PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new BlowfishEngine(), new PKCS7Padding());
        cipher.init(false, new KeyParameter(key.getBytes()));
        byte[] outputConvertedAsBytes = Hex.hex2byte(msg);
        byte[] decryptedAsBytes = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(outputConvertedAsBytes.length)];
        int numberOfBytesCopiedOnDecryptedAsBytes = cipher.processBytes(outputConvertedAsBytes, 0,
                outputConvertedAsBytes.length, decryptedAsBytes, 0);
        cipher.doFinal(decryptedAsBytes, numberOfBytesCopiedOnDecryptedAsBytes);
        return new String(decryptedAsBytes);
    }
}
```

... And this is the main method:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String encrypted = JCEBlowfishEncrypterDecrypter.crypt("Test", "mmTSQOFzSL9xAwXGLMEe1Q==");
        String decrypted = JCEBlowfishEncrypterDecrypter.decrypt(encrypted, "mmTSQOFzSL9xAwXGLMEe1Q==");

        System.out.println("--------------");
        System.out.println("encrypted   -> " + encrypted);
        System.out.println("decrypted -> " + decrypted);
        
        encrypted = BouncyCastleBlowfishEncrypterDecrypter.crypt("Test",
                "mmTSQOFzSL9xAwXGLMEe1Q==");
        decrypted = BouncyCastleBlowfishEncrypterDecrypter.decrypt(encrypted,
                "mmTSQOFzSL9xAwXGLMEe1Q==");

        System.out.println("--------------");
        System.out.println("encrypted   -> " + encrypted);
        System.out.println("decrypted -> " + decrypted);
    }
```

... But I get some strange additional characters when decrypting:
What's wrong?

[image]

Comment: The PKCS#7 padding is missing in the BouncyCastle code. Replace `BufferedBlockCipher` with `PaddedBufferedBlockCipher` and pass `new PKCS7Padding()` as the second parameter in the constructor.

Comment: Well! Now the encryption works, but some additional strange characters are added in the decryption. I've updated the question with an image of the output and updated code: can you see what's wrong?

Comment: The size of the `decryptedAsBytes` array also takes the padding into account. Determine the *actual* size of the decrypted data (i.e. without padding) by adding the return values of `cipher.processBytes()` and `cipher.doFinal()` and apply that size for decoding by using this [`String`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/valhalla/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,int,int,java.nio.charset.Charset)) overload.

Comment: But how should I modify the code to make it work properly? Maybe you can answer directly, then I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime, you have changed your original post, so I refer you to the original post and list all necessary changes:

- The BouncyCastle code is missing the correct handling of the PKCS#7 padding. To enable PKCS#7 padding, `BufferedBlockCipher` must be replaced by `PaddedBufferedBlockCipher` and `PKCS7Padding` must be specified.
- The *strange additional character*s are due to the fact that `cipher.getOutputSize()` returns the size including the padding, which is why the buffer `decryptedAsBytes` after unpadding is larger than the decrypted data. The actual size of the decrypted data (i.e. without padding) can be determined via the return values of `cipher.processBytes()` and `cipher.doFinal()` and used during decoding in conjunction with a suitable `String` overload.

Sample implementation:

```java
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.BlowfishEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PKCS7Padding;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

...

public static String crypt(String msg, String key) throws Exception {
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new BlowfishEngine(), new PKCS7Padding()); // Fix 1: Apply PKCS#7 padding
    cipher.init(true, new KeyParameter(key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    byte[] plaintext = msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] ciphertext = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(plaintext.length)];
    int length = cipher.processBytes(plaintext, 0, plaintext.length, ciphertext, 0);
    cipher.doFinal(ciphertext, length);
    return Hex.toHexString(ciphertext);
}

public static String decrypt(String ciphertextHex, String key) throws Exception {
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new BlowfishEngine(), new PKCS7Padding()); // Fix 1: Apply PKCS#7 padding
    cipher.init(false, new KeyParameter(key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    byte[] ciphertext = Hex.decode(ciphertextHex);
    byte[] decrypted = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(ciphertext.length)];
    int length = cipher.processBytes(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.length, decrypted, 0);
    length += cipher.doFinal(decrypted, length);                                                                // Fix 2: determine the actual size of the decrypted data
    return new String(decrypted, 0, length, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);                                            // only take the actual length into account when decoding
}
```

---

Further issues:

- In the code, the encoding is missing in many `getBytes()` and `new String()` calls. This should be specified, as otherwise the platform-dependent default encoding is used intransparently.
- Possibly, the Base64 decoding of the key is missing in the code (`mmTSQOFzSL9xAwXGLMEe1Q==` is UTF-8 encoded 24 bytes long and Base64 decoded 16 bytes long; technically both are possible, as Blowfish allows key sizes between 4 and 56 bytes; usually the raw key is applied).
- This is probably a legacy application, so the mode and algorithm cannot be changed. But for the sake of completeness: ECB is an insecure mode, better use a mode with IV (e.g. CBC) or even better authenticated encryption. The current standard AES is considered more secure than Blowfish.
- Note that Base64 is more efficient than hex encoding.

Comment: Yes it's on old application adn I can't change it because the output is send to another server. Really really thanks!